# Text wraps around distant element

Tags: html, css

### Problem

I'm trying to create a dynamic info element that sits to the side of other linked DOM elements by setting a large margin. However, I'm stuck with a small issue as the text inside a p element that sits inside the containing div is flowing around the text in the preceding div, despite them not actually being nearby one another.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xZaH7/4/) of problem.

I've found that I can prevent this by making the preceding

elements position absolute, however this presents its own problems and as such, if there were a better way to prevent the issue it would be much more ideal.

HTML

---

```
<br>
<br>
<p id="problem">Text which will cause word wrap.</p>
<div id="container">
    <p>Text which is being wrapped around the text, despite the fact that the text is not nearby</p>
</div>
```

CSS

---

```
#problem {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    width: auto;
}
#container {
    background-color: rgb(255, 150, 150);
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 188px;
    left: 220px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    padding: 4px;
    position: relative;
    top: -22px;
    width: 200px;
}
#container p {
    color: rgb(216, 0, 12);
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 96px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Edit: Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xZaH7/8/) with more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## wrapper {

```
margin-top: 60px;
```

}

## content {

```
background-color: #BBBBBB;
width: 300px;
```

}

## content input {

```
float: right;
```

}

## problem {

```
display: block;
float: left;
height: 16px;
line-height: 16px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 2px;
width: auto;
```

}
.control {
    height: 30px;
    width: auto;
}

## container {

```
background-color: rgb(255, 150, 150);
display: block;
font-size: 14px;
height: 188px;
left: 300px;
margin-left: 15px;
padding: 4px;
position: absolute;

width: 200px;
```

}

## container p {

```
color: rgb(216, 0, 12);
display: block;
font-size: 14px;
height: 96px;
line-height: 16px;
margin: 0;
width: 200px;
```

}

Comment: This seems to work, but I actually need to float the element due to some other arranged elements.  They're not in the Fiddle, as to simplify the problem.  Any ideas outside of this?

Comment: hmm kind of hard to guess at what might effect other elements, can you make a fiddle that displays your situation and I'll give it a crack.

Comment: Here's a somewhat more contextual example: http://jsfiddle.net/xZaH7/5/

Essentially what I have an input container next to the p tag (and several more rows of these in practice) and the design is much nicer with each input sitting next to its descriptor rather than under.

Comment: that example the text isn't wrapping

Comment: Which browser are you viewing it in?  I'm seeing wrapper in every browser I've checked, though not uniform in placement.  Here's a screencap from Chrome: http://s30.postimg.org/ej4r1lwvl/textbrowser.jpg

Comment: ahh gotcha, I thought that line was centered for some reason.

Comment: what if you closed out the control div before the content one.

<div class="control">
            <p id="problem">Problematic text</p>
            <input type="text">
            </div>

Comment: This puts it out of flow with the #problem element.  Pushing the #container back up so that they still appear oriented together by setting a negative margin-top results in the text wrapping again, as here: http://jsfiddle.net/xZaH7/9/

Comment: ok what about setting the container to absolute and removing the margin-top. http://jsfiddle.net/xZaH7/5/

Comment: Seems to be working like a charm, and I can live with that being absolutely positioned.  Not sure why it was flowing around in the first place, but a solution is good enough for me.  Thanks!